# Perl trouble accessing array within hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I've looked around for an answer to this question but haven't found one; thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to construct a hash of arrays and then randomly generate arrays from the hash.  The hash is length 3, and each array is a pair of values:

```
undef %pairs;

$pairs{'one'} = @pair1;
$pairs{'two'} = @pair2;
$pairs{'three'} = @pair3;

@keys = keys %pairs;

@keys = shuffle(@keys);

push (@file1, @{$pairs{$keys[0]}});
push (@file2, @{$pairs{$keys[1]}});
push (@file3, @{$pairs{$keys[2]}});
```

The following call doesn't return anything:

```
    print STDOUT @{$pairs{$keys[0]}};
```

Although the next call does correctly return the length of the array (i.e. 2):

```
    print STDOUT $pairs{$keys[0]};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You are not assigning the arrays, you are assigning their size:

```
$pairs{'one'} = @pair1;
```

When in scalar context, an array returns its size, and this is scalar context. You want either:

```
$pairs{'one'} = \@pair1;      # use direct reference
$pairs{'one'} = [ @pair1 ];   # anonymous reference using copied values
```

Or possibly

```
@{ $pairs{'one'} } = @pair1;
```

Also, you are not using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Or you would already know why this code fails:

```
print STDOUT @{$pairs{$keys[0]}};
```

Because you would have received the fatal error:

```
Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Because your hash value `$pairs{$keys[0]}` is set to `2` (the size of the array).

Comment: +1: Great explanation. It's an absolute joy to read through your answers @TLP.